# What is the motivation and intuition behind the symplectic form?

Tags: matrices, geometry, differential-geometry, symplectic-geometry, bilinear-form

That's the definition we got for the symplectic form:

Let  $$\omega : \: \mathbb{C}^n \times \mathbb{C}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$$ be a bilinear, anti-symmetric and non-degenerate ($\forall_{y \in \mathbb{C}^n} \: \omega(x,y)=0 \: \Rightarrow \: x=0$) map.

Let $e_1, ..., e_n$ be the base of $\mathbb{C}^n$ which means, that for $x, y \in \mathbb{C}^n$ we got $x = \sum x_i e_i$, $y = \sum y_i e_i$
Then, our symplectic form is equal to $$\omega(x,y) = x^T \Omega y$$

My question here is: What does this symplectic form intuitively tell us? How can I understand it in an intuitive way (and not abstract like here)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some informal sources of intuition and motivation:

- *[Why symplectic geometry is the natural setting for classical mechanics](https://math.mit.edu/%7Ecohn/Thoughts/symplectic.html)* by Henry Cohn.
- *[What is a symplectic manifold, really?](https://sbseminar.wordpress.com/2012/01/09/what-is-a-symplectic-manifold-really/)* by Ben Webster.

For some technical detail about the latter, see also my questions 
[Assignment of energy functions to flows is "equivariant"?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/530806/assignment-of-energy-functions-to-flows-is-equivariant) and [Pushforward of Hamiltonian vector field by (reverse) Hamiltonian flow is Hamiltonian](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3554066/pushforward-of-hamiltonian-vector-field-by-reverse-hamiltonian-flow-is-hamilto).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a recommendation: Have a look in Vladimir Arnold´s book *Mathematical Methods of Classical Mechanics*. There the geometric meaning behind the formulae is explained.

Comment: I don't think that this book is available here where I live. Could I maybe get a summary of what's in that book behind the geometric meaning?

Comment: This book is available everywhere with an internet connexion, if you see what I mean.

Answer (score 1):

The best references I have read on the motivation of symplectic geometry are due to Weinstein.

- Pages 23-24 from [Lectures on the Geometry of Quantization](https://math.berkeley.edu/%7Ealanw/GofQ.pdf)
  .
- The article [Symplectic geometry](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/bulletin-of-the-american-mathematical-society-new-series/volume-5/issue-1/Symplectic-geometry/bams/1183548217.full).